# Failed to map the path '/' Visual Studio 2013 IDE (Even as administrator)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I use to be able to connect to my Test Server source code via a Network Drive.

I have mapped it to letter `K`.

My computer (since last restart) won't run the IDE properly, and always displays the error `ASP.NET runtime error: Failed to map the path '/'.` at the top of the `.aspx` file.

[image: Error at top of aspx file]

I have tried the following:

- Starting Visual Studio as administrator
- [image: Visual Studio is started with UAC]
- Ensuring that my user has FULL rights to the source code folder (both from the network drive and the server)
- [image: Folder properties of mapped network drive]
- Given Network Service and Network users on the server full control over the test server source code folder.
- Changing the AppPool identity on the test server to use my username (as I am administrator on the server as well).
- Creating a new website project and mapping it on another network drive (Still doesn't resolve the problem).

When I access the test server via my web browser I receive no errors. So I know there is no errors in my code.

If I open the IDE on the server using remote desktop then it works with no errors.

I can live with the error on the top of the page, however when I try to access a DataSet or a Control on the page then it doesn't register the control or function as an existing function.

I am now at a complete loss as to how I am going to fix this.

Any ideas on what could cause this issue and how I could fix it?

Comment: I appologize if I posted in the wrong section, I did not know if this needs to go to ServerFault or StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to the problem by opening the code directly using the IIS on the server.

What I did was click on `File` -> `Open Website`, in the open dialog, on the left, I clicked "Local IIS", found my TestServer and clicked open.

[image: Steps to follow]